# System.Collections hashtable - search for most recently added match

Tags: .net, search, hashtable

I have a hashtable with id-name value pairs. The id is entered as the key, and the name as the value. I am then searching the table, and returning the key whose value matches a specified string like this: (folderValue is the specified string)

```
String^ key;
for each (String^ aKey in table.Keys)
{
    if ((String^)table.default[aKey] == folderValue)
    {
        key = aKey;
        break;
    }
}
```

My question is, there might be more than one value that matches folderValue. Is there any way to start searching from the most recent entries and back?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a fairly non-standard way to use a hashtable.  How are you using this data?  Consider alternate data structures, like perhaps a `List<MyCustomClass>`, where `MyCustomClass` contains ID, Name, and implements IComparable that considers a date or other time-based data.  Retrieve items from this list, and sort them.  Using LINQ against this would give you a nice way to retrieve data.